# Ordenar INSERT Mysql con 2 ciclos

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo una duda que no se como resolver,
tengo dos ciclos distintos uno viene de un select con array y
Estos son los ciclos:
Este el que viene del select

```
    $query_parts = array();
        for ($t=0;$t<count($fname);$t++)
        {
            $query_parts[] = "'" . $fname[$t] . "'"; 

        }
```

Y este el que viene de los INPUTS:

```
    for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){
        $query_parts1[] = "('" . date('Y-m-d') . "','" . $_POST["lname$i"] . "','" . $_POST["lref$i"] . "', '" . $_POST["lobs$i"] . "')";
        }
```

me genera esto:

```
    ('T 109','T 108','T 12')
  ;
```

por otro lado tengo otro ciclo que viene de unos INPUTS que me genera esto:

```
    ('2021-04-12','11111','1', '1'),('2021-04-12','22222','2', '2')
```

El resultado que busco para que me funcione INSERT MULTIPLE es :

```
    ('T 109','2021-04-12','11111','1', '1'),('T 109','2021-04-12','22222','2', '2'),('T 108','2021-04-12','11111','1', '1'),('T 108','2021-04-12','22222','2', '2'),('T 12','2021-04-12','11111','1', '1'),('T 12','2021-04-12','22222','2', '2')
```

El número de SELECT e INPUTS casi nunca van a coincidir por eso lo tengo separado (seguro que se puede hacer junto )
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: No entendí muy bien tu pregunta. Sin embargo hay aquí un tema muy importante que no estás tomando en cuenta: **la seguridad**. Hacer funcionar un código como el tuyo supondría una puerta ancha abierta de par en par a ataques de *Inyección SQL*, es un agujero de seguridad que expondría tu servidor a todo tipo de ataque, por SQL se puede incluso modificar/insertar archivos en el sistema. Deberías resolver esto con consultas preparadas, escribiendo tu consulta con marcadores `?` para cada valor y pasando los valores de los arrays con `bind_param`. Pero no entendí lo que dices en tu último párrafo

Comment: Gracias, el tema de la seguridad no es fundamental porque es un servidor local sin acceso exterior, sólo sirve para controlar unos movimientos y sacar luego unos listados. En el último párrafo lo que indico es que puedo tener 2 SELECT que arrojan dos resultados , sin embargo puedo tener 20 INPUTS, por lo que cada INPUT se multiplica por el número de SELECT. Muchas gracias

Comment: La seguridad **siempre es importante**, además usar consultas preparadas significa también optimizar el código. Creo que ayudaría que verbalices el problema. Parece que quieres incluir como primer valor de cada INSERT el valor que viene en el array de los inputs ¿es así? Sigo sin entender el último párrafo. Puede que esto incluso sea un problema donde estás generando los datos (en un HTML supongo). Si verbalizas el problema podremos sugerirte una mejor forma de hacerlo. A veces uno se centra en problemas sobre un código, pero puede que ese sea un problema derivado de otro a nivel de lógica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sería iterar sobre los dos arreglos y hacer un merge:

Datos de entrada de ejemplo:

```
$arraySelect = array ( 0 => 'T 109', 1 => 'T 108', 2 => 'T 12');
$arrayInput = array ( 0 => array ( 0 => '2021-04-12', 1 => '11111', 2 => '1', 3 => '1', ), 1 => array ( 0 => '2021-04-12', 1 => '22222', 2 => '2', 3 => '2', ));
```

Codigo php:

```
$arrayResult = array();

foreach($arraySelect AS $asElemento) {
    foreach($arrayInput AS $aiElemento) {
        $arrayResult[] = array_merge(array($asElemento), $aiElemento);
    }
}
```

Salida (var_export($arrayResult)):

```
array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'T 109', 1 => '2021-04-12', 2 => '11111', 3 => '1', 4 => '1', ), 1 => array ( 0 => 'T 109', 1 => '2021-04-12', 2 => '22222', 3 => '2', 4 => '2', ), 2 => array ( 0 => 'T 108', 1 => '2021-04-12', 2 => '11111', 3 => '1', 4 => '1', ), 3 => array ( 0 => 'T 108', 1 => '2021-04-12', 2 => '22222', 3 => '2', 4 => '2', ), 4 => array ( 0 => 'T 12', 1 => '2021-04-12', 2 => '11111', 3 => '1', 4 => '1', ), 5 => array ( 0 => 'T 12', 1 => '2021-04-12', 2 => '22222', 3 => '2', 4 => '2', ), ).
```

Para realizar los INSERTs puedes utilizar Prepared statments (bind_param and execute los puedes ejecutar dentro de los foreachs anteriores):

```
//Tu conección a la base de datos
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

//La query para insertar los registros
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO nombre_tabla (nombres_campos) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

foreach($arraySelect AS $asElemento) {
    foreach($arrayInput AS $aiElemento) {
        list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) = array_merge(array($asElemento), $aiElemento);

        //Seteas lo valores para el insert. El primer parámetro especifica los tipos de datos de los valores.
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $a, $b, $c, $d, $e);

        //Ejecutas el INSERT.
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Utilizar Prepared Statments tiene dos ventajas:

- Mayor seguridad: evitas ataques de tipo SQL Injection.
- Mayor rapidéz: ya que el motor de base de datos parsea la query una sola vez, y no cada vez que la ejecutás.

---

Para parsear los valores ingresados por el usuario puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$inputs = array();

for($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) {
    $inputs[] = array(date('Y-m-d'), $_POST["lname{$i}"], $_POST["lref{$i}"], $_POST["lobs{$i}"]);
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122948/discussion-on-answer-by-nachospiu-ordenar-insert-mysql-con-2-ciclos).